# Using useCallback in child component for parent callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

I have a component library  used by several apps, and I use a callback passed in as a prop in useEffect.  Is it Ok to wrap this in useCallback  in this child component just in case the parent component did not? And also so the parent does not need to.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const cb = () => { ... };
  return <Widget condition={true} callback={cb} />
};

const Widget = ({condition, callback}) => {
  const safeCallback = useCallback(callback, [callback]);
  useEffect(() => {
     safeCallback();
  }, [condition, safeCallback]);
}
```

What if the parent DID use useCallback, and it happens twice?

```
const Parent = () => {
  const cb = () => { ... };
  const safeCb = useCallback(cb, [cb]);
  return <Widget condition={true} callback={safeCb} />
};

const Widget = ({condition, callback}) => {
  const safeCallback = useCallback(callback, [callback]);
  useEffect(() => {
     safeCallback();
  }, [condition, safeCallback]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should ask yourself, if you really need the callback inside a `useEffect`. Maybe it can be refactored to be inside an event handler instead.
You can read more about getting rid of effects [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect).

If this is not an option the way, you can make sure, not to pass an unstable reference to a `useEffect` is this:

```
const Widget = ({ callback, condition }) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current();
  }, [condition]);
}
```

Comment: is the useRef pattern preferrable to useCallback?

Comment: i wouldn't say "preferable", but it makes sense situationally. you don't necessarily want to re-run the callback every time it changes, only when `condition` changes. the `useRef` solution here doesn't care whether `callback` is wrapped in `useCallback` or not, and will only run it when `condition` changes.

Comment: if you provide the actual code for `Parent`, `Widget`, `callback` and `condition`, it's possible a better solution can be recommended.

Comment: the [linked guide](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) is a very important read, even for veteran React developers. we've seen many victims of self-induced pain due to API misuse or other anti-patterns.